# how send $data to fetchOne apigility rest?

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

how can send `$data` (some one values->array) to Rest Apigility for make a query and return the result this is my code for send `$data`

```
$body = $this->getRequest()->getContent();
    $json = json_decode($body, true);
    $conditions =array(
            'artist'    =>  $json['data']
    );
    $client = new Client();

    $uri = "http://localhost:81/ApigilityNew/public/albums";

    $user        = 'admin';
    $password    = 'admin';

    //url del servicio REST
    $client->setUri($uri);
    //establecer metodo GET-POST
    $client->setMethod('GET');
    //tiempo de peticion
    $client->setOptions(
            [
                    'maxredirects'  => 0,
                    'timeout'       => 60
            ]
    );
    $client->setHeaders(['Accept' => 'application/json', 'Contet-Type' => 'application/json']);
    $client->setAuth($user, $password , $client::AUTH_BASIC);
    $client->setParameterGet($conditions);
    $response = $client->send($client->getRequest());
```

**for get `$data` on Apigility this:**

**AlbumResource.php**

```
   /**
     * Fetch a resource
     *
     * @param  array $condiciones
     * @return ApiProblem|mixed
     */
    public function fetch($conditions) //$id
    {
        //return new ApiProblem(405, 'The GET method has not been defined for individual resources');
        return $this->mapper->fetchOne($condiciones);
    }
```

**AlbumMapper.php**

```
  public function fetchOne($conditions) 
    {

        $sql = ' SELECT album.id, album.artist, album.title, pais.nombre_pais, biografia.genero, biografia.ocupacion, biografia.sitio_web
                 FROM album
                    LEFT JOIN pais ON  pais.id_album = album.id
                    LEFT JOIN biografia ON biografia.id_album = album.id
                WHERE 1 = 1 ';

        if (!empty($conditions['criterio_busqueda']))
        {
            $sql = $sql. " AND album.artist LIKE '%".$condiciones['criterio_busqueda']."%'";
        }

        $resultset = $this->adapter->query($sql, array($data));
        $data = $resultset->toArray();
        if (!$data) {
            return false;
        }
        return $data;
    }//end function
```

How can get a result? Now it only returns *unsupport media type* from Apigility

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your `ContentType` header:

```
'Contet-Type' => 'application/json'
```

should be:

```
'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
```

That is probably why you get a *unsupported media type* message

Comment: i'm  using this for guide but don't work [link]https://github.com/akrabat/apigility-music-api/blob/master/module/Music/src/Music/V1/Rest/Album/AlbumResource.php

Comment: @DiegoA. That application should work fine. Can you be more specific in your about what the problem is. Do you get an error message? What message? When and where do you get it? Please add a quote of the exact message...